# Trying to mock GetConnect in Flutter for unit testing

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, flutter-getx

I am trying to Mock the GetConnect service in my Flutter app for unit testing.

This is how my mock looks like:

```
class MockGetConnect extends Mock implements GetConnect {}
```

And this is how I am setting it up:

```
  setUpAll(() {
    Get.put<GetConnect>(MockGetConnect());
  });
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'InternalFinalCallback<void>'
  test/core/services/duty_service_test.dart 55:7              MockGetConnect.onStart
  package:get/get_instance/src/get_instance.dart 253:9        GetInstance._startController
  package:get/get_instance/src/get_instance.dart 204:11       GetInstance._initDependencies
  package:get/get_instance/src/get_instance.dart 301:17       GetInstance.find
  package:get/get_instance/src/get_instance.dart 86:12        GetInstance.put
  package:get/get_instance/src/extension_instance.dart 89:21  Inst.put
```

I am injecting it into my class and spend so much time trying to figure this out but to no prevail ;(

Does anyone know how to properly mock out the GetConnect service?

Thanks!

Comment: check here: 
https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/blob/master/NULL_SAFETY_README.md